# bootstrap modal not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a modal popup on a site using bootstrap. The site is departmental so the only code I've got access to is the body of the site basically (everything else is in php includes for the header, footer, and navigation) I've got the bootstrap.js file included as well as jquery. I'm using the example code on the bootstrap docs. I've got bootstrap tooltips and popovers working but can't figure out why the modal won't work.

```html
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button, the page gets backdropped but the only thing in the modal dialog is the navigation bar (I don't have access to the code for that) and the modal dialog in my code (#myModal) is not displayed at all. I have no idea what's going on. This is one my first web development projects.

I want the modal button to be after a select in a form

```php
<select class="bootstrap-select" name=display>

    <?php foreach ($digitalSignageDisplays as $display) { ?>

        <option value=<?php echo $display; ?>><?php echo $display; ?></option>

    <?php } ?>

</select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Could it be a Z-index problem?

Comment: I think you are missing the `data-target` attribute on your button like this: `data-target="#myModal"`

Comment: Are you loading in the javascript for bootstrap?  You also want to change the `x` to `&times;`

Comment: @JasonSperske He has the `href` set to `#myModal`.  I don't think you need the `data-target`.  It looks like he/she just copied/pasted the code from the documentation too.

Comment: The code is directly from the bootstrap docs. They dont have the data-target in theirs. I tried adding the code but still got the same issue. yes im loading the bootstrap js file. got this at the top of my file <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Comment: also, when I try and exit the modal (which isnt appearing so I just click anywhere on the page to dismiss it) the site hangs. sounds like something going wrong with the js

Comment: editted question. The whole page gets backdropped and for some reason the navigation bar of my site is the modal dialog (no idea why its doing that. The navigation bar is near the top of the page) instead of displaying the modal I specified

Comment: Have you added `<script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js">`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't forget to wrap your modal-header , modal-body and modal footer with `<div class="modal-dialog">` and `<div class="modal-content">`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    <link href="D:/install/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    </head>
<body>

<a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Launch demo modal</a>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
            </div><!-- ./modal-header -->


            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body…</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

        </div><!-- ./modal-content -->

    </div><!-- ./modal-dialog -->

</div><!-- ./modal -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="D:/install/bootstrap-3.0.0/assets/js/jquery.js" ></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:/install/bootstrap-3.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" > </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can remove just class hide from  'modal hide fade'  and add just modal - content  .
 Remaining  your code is done perfect.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```